# What effect or similar to it is shown in this video?

Tags: photoshop

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CmftPUqQ0nE at 3:42 suddenly the photo becomes grainy or something. I can't replicate it since the uploader  disabled the comments section and description is not helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

An effect like this can be achieved with a high pass filter. To do this, duplicate the layer (Ctrl+J, Cmd+J on a Mac). Put a high pass filter on the top layer (fairly small radius, i.e. less than around 2 pixels) and then set the blend mode of the layer to overlay.

EDIT: If you convert to a smart object before applying the high pass filter, you can play with the radius afterwards.